# PySpark write to csv by removing scale from decimal columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to write the dataframe to CSV file and while writing the file remove the scale value. If the scale is `00` else write along with the scale.

For example, say I have below dataframe.

```
+--------------+--------+--------+
|       id     |date    |amount  |
+--------------+--------+--------+
|12345678911.00|11/24/17|  203.02|
|12345678911.00|11/24/17|   13.52|
|12345678912.00|11/24/17|   28.00|
|12345678913.00|11/24/17|  105.71|
|12345678914.00|11/24/17|    7.68|
|12345678915.00|11/24/17|    0.18|
|12345678916.00|11/24/17|  530.38|
|12345678917.00|11/24/17|    1.79|
|12345678918.00|11/24/17|   35.00|
|12345678923.00|11/24/17|    8.84|
|12345678922.00|11/24/17|  150.47|
|12345678922.00|11/24/17|   39.00|
|12345678925.00|11/24/17|    6.46|
|12345678927.00|11/24/17|    2.59|
|12345678928.00|11/24/17|   25.00|
|12345678929.00|11/24/17|   44.04|
|12345678930.00|11/24/17|    3.90|
|12345678933.00|11/24/17|   50.00|
|12345678932.00|11/24/17|    6.26|
|12345678931.00|11/24/17|   10.90|
+--------------+--------+--------+
```

While we write to csv file, the output should remove `.00` from each rows for all the columns of decimal type. 
We are reading the value from csv by passing the schema, where we define few columns of `DecimalType`.

Expected output would be.

```
+--------------+--------+--------+
|       id     |date    |amount  |
+--------------+--------+--------+
|12345678911   |11/24/17|  203.02|
|12345678911   |11/24/17|   13.52|
|12345678912   |11/24/17|      28|
|12345678913   |11/24/17|  105.71|
|12345678914   |11/24/17|    7.68|
|12345678915   |11/24/17|    0.18|
|12345678916   |11/24/17|  530.38|
|12345678917   |11/24/17|    1.79|
|12345678918   |11/24/17|      35|
|12345678923   |11/24/17|    8.84|
|12345678922   |11/24/17|  150.47|
|12345678922   |11/24/17|      39|
|12345678925   |11/24/17|    6.46|
|12345678927   |11/24/17|    2.59|
|12345678928   |11/24/17|      25|
|12345678929   |11/24/17|   44.04|
|12345678930   |11/24/17|    3.90|
|12345678933   |11/24/17|      50|
|12345678932   |11/24/17|    6.26|
|12345678931   |11/24/17|   10.90|
+--------------+--------+--------+
```

I tried to cast it to StringType, but it didnt help much. 
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing result with `regexp_replace` and writing output as strings is the closest thing you can get:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("203.02", ), ("0.18", ), ("3", ), ("10.90", )],
    ("amount", )
).withColumn("amount", col("amount").cast("decimal(38, 2)"))

df.select(regexp_replace("amount", "\\.00$", "")).show()
#+-------------------------------+
#|regexp_replace(amount, \.00$, )|
#+-------------------------------+
#|                         203.02|
#|                           0.18|
#|                              3|
#|                          10.90|
#+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Also is it possible to strip of additional zero , i.e instead of `10.90` i would like to save that as `10.9`. ?

Comment: `"(\\.00$|(?<=\\.[1-9])0)"`?